# Background-image for a PNG File

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve this effect:

[image]

You see see a PNG-photo (in this case a woman), and a background-photo of a mountain. If I try a background-image for the PNG-file in CSS, it doesn't work. I don't want the text inside.

Comment: why don't you just create an image like this ?

Comment: I only want to use CSS (or Javascript). The background-image has the property "position: fixed" and the PNG-file "width: 60vw". So if I resize the screen, the image doesn't look the same.

Comment: the way this is achieved is that there is a mountain image on the first layer, then the next layer above it has a white background with a cutout of a woman, overlaying these two will give you the desired effect.

Comment: Here is a good article about css masking
https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/mask-image/

Keep in mind this is not compatible with IE and old browsers

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so far, so we can help you debug or improve it. That's how Stackoverflow works.